# query mysql Updating Stock Issue

Tags: mysql, updating

i am using this query and works good (if TblExistencias.codigo exist), But if i dont have TblExistencias.codigo i need update TblPartes.stock = 0 too

The query that i am using is

```
update TblParts set stock= (select count(*) from TblExistencias where 
TblExistencias.code = TblParts.code)
```

for example, if i have `TblParts.code = xxx` and Code `TblExistencias.code` Not `Exist`, Must Update TblParts.code(xxx) to 0 too

How can i add this to the query?

Comment: Time to explore using a `JOIN` instead of this subquery mess.

Comment: thanks for response, i try a few joins but i cant make this work.

Answer (score 0):

Use coalesce to return a zero:

```
update TblParts 
    set stock = coalesce((select count(*) 
        from TblExistencias 
        where TblExistencias.code = TblParts.code),0)
```

Comment: Could you possibly be more vague? What "didn't work"?

Comment: When a Product Code Not Exist In TblExistencias.code but Exist in TblParts.code is Not updated to 0 in TblParts.stock